# док-панель для веб-приложения

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: док-панель Yandex Q]

здравствуйте, новичок пока в разработке веб-приложении. Хотелось бы узнать как сделать такую панельку, только чтоб она не пропадала с виду.

Comment: .dock-panel {
 position: fixed;
    top: 88%;
    right: ;
    z-index: 100;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 30px auto;
 background-color: #9D9D9D;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
 border-radius: 30px;
 height: 50px;
}

Comment: написал такой код, вот только проблемы с координацией. не могу сделать так чтоб она стояло именно по центру внизу

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно создать область, постоянно висящую на экране при помощи свойства `position:fixed`, закрепив ее в самом верху (`top:0`) или в низу экрана (`bottom:0`) и растянув на всю ширину: `width:100%`.
2. Для удобства центрирования содержимого можно использовать `display:flex` в сочетании с `justify-content:center`;
3. Внутри фиксированной области можно поместить собственно функциональную панель с кнопками, внешними отступами, тенью. Она может как угодно менять ширину, в зависимости от набора кнопок, но всегда останется посередине экрана.
4. Чтобы прозрачная фиксированная область пропускала сквозь себя клики по ссылкам на странице, пригодится свойство `pointer-events:none`; Панелька с кнопками унаследует это свойство, ей оно не нужно, т.к. она должна "ловить" клики: `pointer-events:auto`.